# Reduce div height from top using jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I am trying to do is that when an event is called the div `#target`'s height is reduced/increased from top or top content is hidden/visible to a specific size. I can't think of a way to do that.

The following code reduces/adds height from bottom but what I want it to reduce from top.

```js
$(function() {

  $("button:first").on("click", function() {
    $("#target").css("height", "+=50px");
  });

  $("button:last").on("click", function() {
    $("#target").css("height", "-=50px");
  });
});
```

```css
#target {
  background: purple;
  color: white;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
}

div {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button>PLUS</button>
  <button>MINUS</button>
</div>
<div id="target">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Is that code is not working ??  And is the function working when user click the button??

Comment: Its working but it reduces/adds height from bottom.. but what I want it to reduce from top

Comment: can you upload your code at jsbin?? and provide the link

Comment: if you cut from your content will be hampered...

Comment: yes I know but this content is just for demo .. my real content will be compatible with it

Comment: There is no such specific way but I can help you by doing that with margin

Comment: @Ashish ... https://jsbin.com/bumuxudexi/edit?html,output

Comment: any suggestion will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the current height of the element, then do whatever math on it, and then set the new CSS value.

P.S. 
It will always add and reduce from the bottom because that is the way that the browser renders content. From top left to bottom right. So if you add or subtract height it will be from the bottom.

This should work.

```
$("button:first").on("click", function() {
    var targ = $("#target"),
          targHt = targ.height(),
          newTargHt = targHt + 50;

    targ.height(newTargHt);
});

$("button:last").on("click", function() {
    var targ = $("#target"),
          targHt = targ.height(),
          newTargHt = targHt - 50;

    targ.height(newTargHt);
});
```

Comment: your code will do the samething what my code does... I know that browser renders content. From top left to bottom right.. but I hope someone will have a way around that :-)

Comment: Form my understanding that isn't anything we can control from JS. You would need a language like C++.

Comment: thanks for your time... you were partially right... some CSS did the trick

Answer (score 0):

hey have a look on this bin : https://jsbin.com/wiqapadeza/edit?html,js,output
I have used margin property to solve your issue:

```
$(function() {
 var top=0;
 $("button:first").on("click", function() {
    top=top+50;
    $("#target").css("height", "+=50px");
    $("p").css("margin-top", top);
  });
 $("button:last").on("click", function() {
  top=top-50;
    $("#target").css("height", "-=50px");
  $("p").css("margin-top", top);
 });
});
```

I hope it helps you:

Comment: Did this helped you?

Comment: there arises a problem with text content in bottom .. when i click minus

Comment: What is the probelm can you explain??

Comment: You need to explain it clearly...People are not able to get it

Comment: in your given link of JSBin when the minus button is pressed the text gets jumbled up.. thats the problem... I hope you get it now

Comment: So what should happen if i click on  minus button

Comment: https://jsbin.com/wiqapadeza/edit?html,js,output  .. this was your output..right!
When pressed minus button...The target is that my div's height decreases from top without affecting the content inside but your output jumbles up the text inside in the bottom and more when pressed again

Comment: thanks for your time.... I figured it out.. some modification in css did it